# how to give hide/delete and copy the div when hold on that div using jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, contextmenu

We are developing chat application using jquery mobile in worklight.

In that application we are showing the message,images and voice record. so i want to do when hold any thing like message,image,voice record file on that div i need to show copy and clear/delete option and if delete or option is selected i want do that functionality and if it is copy i want to do that functionality.

But i am trying to tab hold event from jquery mobile but it is not working. any one please tell me how to do for my requirement.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate","#chat",function(){
   $(".clear").on("taphold",function(){
    alert("jf")
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).simpledialog2({
          mode:"blank",
          headerText:"Image Options",
          showModal:false,
          forceInput:true,
          headerClose:true,
          blankContent:"<ul data-role='listview'><li>Clear/Delete</li><li>Copy</li></ul>"
      });
    
   });                       
 });
```

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 25px 20px 25px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #fff;
  clear: both;
}

div{
  clear:right
}

.name, 
.time {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.name {
  top: 2px;
  color: #900;
}

.right .name {
  right: 4px;
}

.time {
  bottom: 2px;
  color: #f60;
}

.right .time {
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <div class="name">fsdfsfsfsdfdsfsdfsf</div>
  <span>thanks</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="name">fsdfs</div>
  <span>thanks</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="name">fsdfs</div>
  <span>t</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69ya1b1x/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all code seems fine. Can you confirm whether you have included simpledialog script. Add jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js . This could be the only reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Touch issue SO </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
 <style>
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 25px 20px 25px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #fff;
  clear: both;
}

div{
  clear:right
}

.name, 
.time {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.name {
  top: 2px;
  color: #900;
}

.right .name {
  right: 4px;
}

.time {
  bottom: 2px;
  color: #f60;
}

.right .time {
  left: 4px;
}

  </style>



</head>
<body>

<div class="right">
  <div class="name">Demo</div>
  <span>thanks</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="name">Demo2</div>
  <span>thanks</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="name">Wow</div>
  <span>t</span>
  <div class="time">time</div>
</div>

<script>
 $(".right").on("taphold", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).simpledialog2({
        mode:"blank",
        headerText:"Image Options",
        showModal:false,
        forceInput:true,
        headerClose:true,
        blankContent:"<ul data-role='listview'><li>Clear/Delete</li><li>Copy</li></ul>"
    });
});





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I verified its working fine.
-Anil

Comment: i don't want pop at least i want hide the which ever hold the div https://jsfiddle.net/69ya1b1x/4/